# Find minimum of the sigma

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization, number-theory

Is there any polynomial algorithm to finding x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>,...,x<sub>n</sub> for fixed  a<sub>i,j</sub>,p<sub>i,j</sub> and g<sub>i,j</sub> and (0 < i,j <= n) such that minimize sigma{p<sub>i,j</sub>c<sub>i,j</sub>} where :

a<sub>i,j</sub>+x<sub>i</sub>-x<sub>j</sub> = c<sub>i,j</sub> (mod g<sub>i,j</sub>) , -1< c<sub>i,j</sub> < g<sub>i,j</sub>

Comment: I wonder if http://math.stackexchange.com wouldn't be a better place for this question.

Comment: I did it before but I don't get any answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x = a (mod b)` is the same as: there is an integer `q` such that `a + qb = x` is integer, therefore, `x = a (mod b)` constraint is equivalent to `x - bW = a, W >= 0`, `W` is integral, i.e., your problem can be reformulated as a mixed-integer program, which is know to be [NP-hard problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming).